# Refusal of a visit visa to the UK

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

Applied for a visa to visit my uncle in the UK but was refused giving the following reasons:

They said I applied to to visit my aunt (which I never stated in my application) but brought supporting documents from my uncle stating his willingness to bear the cost of my trip, meaning there's no personal or professional relation between us (actually when filling the form there was a question that went like what's the relation of the person in the UK to you but there wasn't uncle in the options provided so I chose other relative and added his contact details and address so I don't know where the aunt came from, does choosing other relative mean aunt or something?)

Secondly they said I stated in my application I'm a non working student and that I attached a bank statement with a closing balance of over 200GBP and that they aren't satisfied with the evidence of the source or the money is for my exclusive use (I don't really get this point, are non working students required to have a specific amount before applying or what?)

Lastly they said I said the cost of the trip to me personally was 300GBP but I had less than that in my account so I can't sustain myself in the UK does it not contradict the second reason?) they also said I stated I had 300USD for the trip but the cost of flight was 285USD and my living expenses 200USD meaning I'm short of 185 (I thought they just needed an information about these so provided them because my uncle was bearing the cost of my trip so attached all the necessary documents to the invite not knowing they calculated using the money my account, how was I supposed to answer the questions under income in expenditure in the case where my sponsor that's my uncle was bearing all the cost of my trip? Can I apply again? And how many times can I apply after refusal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply again, and I believe there's no limit to how many times you can apply for a UK visa unless there's a ban.

- Make another application and pay
- Present your proof / documents again but get new and better documents if possible (remember you want this to be presented and understood better that your previous application, make sure it makes sense to you and get someone else to have a look)
- Refer to your previous application, point out their mistakes or what information they have overlooked in your previous application. Do not be aggressive or rude, simply provide, for each point in the rejection letter what they have overlooked and why they are wrong. Refer to new document if you have provided any.
- I like to always provide an itinerary of my visit, you can do the same. it shows you have a plan.
- Let them know you have an interest back home that will make you return (you don't have to say it verbatim, but provide a hint)

Good luck.

Comment: There is no opportunity to appeal a visit visa refusal.  [Immigration Act 2014](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/22/contents/enacted).  Would you please fix your answer so that the OP is not misled?   I will be able to  cancel my down vote then.

Comment: Actually I had no right to appeal or administrative review

Comment: @GayotFow Removed the `if you have right of appeal...` bit. Thanks @deitz for confirming that.

Comment: @yinka, Thanks.  My down vote is cancelled.  The community is deciding whether the question is a duplicate or not. If so, it will not affect your rep on the site.

Comment: @yinka ,with my bank statement , what do you think will be the best thing to do when applying again?I'm a non working student who receives money from home every month. I provided my statement and learnt there's no evidence of origin or that it's for exclusive use

Comment: How do I provide the hint by letting them know I've an interest at home that will make me come back. @yinka

Comment: A letter from your Uncle saying he will be responsible for your accommodation and upkeep, his bank statement and last 3 payslip should help. Showing keenness to return to your studies after your holiday, family ties back home may also help.

Comment: He stated that in the invite he sent to me and also do I have to state in the application that I'll return to my studies after holiday?do I have to add my bank statement to my next application? @yinka